# Cloud Computing: What does it take to setup a Cloud

Tags: hosting, cloud

What does it take to setup a cloud. I have some friends in the middle east who want to setup clouds similar to Google and Amazon and are wondering if there is any open technology that they can use to setup a cloud hosting service. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "a cloud"? A cloud computing service? Cloud storage?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but is'nt Cloud Computing supposed to encompass both Service and Storage? The way I think of a cloud is a limitless(ofcourse I don't live in the real world) resource where I deploy my site and then don't have to worry about storage, cpu etc. And I am billed for my usage of the resources.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are a few open source cloud servers:

- http://www.eucalyptus.cloud
- http://www.enomaly.com/
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/eyeos/ (semi-"cloud")

Answer (score 10):

You should check out [Eucalyptus](http://www.eucalyptus.com/).  The goal of Eucalyptus is to allow you to setup your own private cloud, similar to Amazon's EC2.

Answer (score 2):

Software is important and there is nothing available publicly that replicates what you might find in Google, Microsoft or Amazon. Microsoft has written the most about their infrastructure. [AutoPilot](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64604) and [Cost of Clouds](http://www.mvdirona.com/jrh/TalksAndPapers/CostOfClouds_CCR.pdf) being two interesting papers. A real segment of the cost will be in data center design and construction. The number of computers needed is non trivial. To be clear I don't think that a single cluster of 5000 machines is a cloud. Many clusters of 5000 machines is a cloud. Also clouds should be resilient to data center failure so there should probably be at least two data centers.

Other than geo-location is there any reason they want to have their own and not use either EC2 or Azure?

Comment: @crowne Nice. +1, but wish I could +Infinity.

Answer (score 2):

Recently VMWare announced Cloud Foundry. Cloud Foundry is both a commercial product and open source project. [cloudfoundry.com](http://www.cloudfoundry.com) is the websiter of the commercial service. The open-source project is homed at [cloudfoundry.org](http://www.cloudfoundry.org), source code is on [github](https://github.com/cloudfoundry).

So far what I have seen, suggests that the cloud software, and consequently the service, being developed by cloudfoundry is more of a [PaaS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_as_a_service) offering than [IaaS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrastructure_as_a_Service#Infrastructure). This might appear surprising given the fact that VMWare's core strength is virtualization.

For your requirement you can probably build the whole cloud solution by combining cloud foundry's OSS with other open source IaaS software like [Eucalyptus](http://www.eucalyptus.com/) to make your own complete stack.

Answer (score 1):

"Cloud" is an often misunderstood term.

Any computer doing any work on the internet qualifies as cloud.  It's simply a metaphor for computer work done "somewhere else".

Perhaps you meant [distributed computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_computing)?

Comment: There is a huge difference between cloud computing and distributed computing. Please read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing

Comment: Cloud means remote. If I host your documents on a server at my house, it's cloud computing. Usually as a service provider, I should offer performance and redundancy and so on. But even without, it is still cloud computing. It's meaning less buzzword.

Comment: So the condensation on my overclocked, water-cooled CPU doesn't count then eh?

Answer (score 1):

Rackspace's solution set is running on [OpenStack](http://openstack.org).